# Mapping a Map<> parameter of a REST call in OpenApi 3.0

Tags: spring-boot, rest, openapi

I have a @RestController in a Springboot application and one of the REST methods has this parameter:

```
            @Parameter(description = "My example")
            @RequestPart(required = false)
            Map<String, List<String>> someData
```

When we were using Swagger v2, the api-docs showed this as a body parameter, e.g.:

```
"/pathto/mymethod": {
  "post": {
    "parameters": [
       ....
       {
            "in": "body",
            "name": "someData",
            "description": "My example",
            "required": false,
            "schema": {
                "$ref": "#/definitions/MetadataMap"
            }
        }
      ....
      ]
    }
  }
```

However, we've moved to OpenApi 3.0 and now this parameter has just disappeared from the api-docs.

I tried to annotate it with:

```
            @Parameter(description = "My example")
            @Schema(
                description = "Description of the parameter",
                type = "object",
                implementation = HashMap.class,
                subTypes = {String.class},
                example = "{ \"key\": [\"value1\", \"value2\"] }"
            )
            @RequestPart(required = false)
            Map<String, List<String>> someData
```

It still doesn't work.
I also made this parameter a class instead of an interface, i.e. HashMap<String, List> someData, and still it doesn't work.

So what is wrong here ? How can I make this parameter of type Map<String, List> visible in OpenApi 3.0 api-docs ?

Comment: You might need to annotate it as [`@RequestBody`](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Swagger-2.X---Annotations#requestbody) instead of `@Parameter`.

Comment: @Helen you're mixing up spring boot annotations with springdoc annotations. `@Parameter` is a springdoc one.

Comment: right, @RequestBody is not what we are looking for here; there must be a way to annotate this REST method in order to produce something like in swagger v2:
"MetadataMap": {
   "type": "object",
   "properties": {
    "key": {
     "type": "string"
    },
    "value": {
     "type": "array",
     "items": {
      "type": "string"
     }
    }
   }
  }

Answer (score 0):

In a post on springdoc-openapi project of 3 years ago we're getting a clue: https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi/issues/597

"In fact its normal that Maps are ignored"

The solution is given in the same post:
"With v1.3.4, you have a first workaround which is:

```
static {
    SpringDocUtils.getConfig().removeRequestWrapperToIgnore(java.util.Map.class);
}
```

"